# Serializing POCO Entities

Tags: .net, serialization, entity-framework-4, poco

Can I serialize POCO classes? I'm using the C# POCO entity generator.

I tried to edit the .tt file which generates the entity classes to add the Serializable attribute.  Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using POCO proxies, not pure POCOs. Pure POCOs can be serialized if (obviously) they're serializable. Proxies might not be.

Comment: How can I serialize POCOs if I'm using the ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator for generating the POCO entities?  And when I set the context's ProxyCreationEnabled property to false, proxy creation is already disabled so I'm sure I'm not using those proxies.

Comment: You can always serialize real POCOs. If you're using proxies, which aren't really POCOs, then you should project onto real POCOs. I generally project onto anonymous types before serializing, as this guarantees no circular references, which typically kill serialization anyway.

Comment: Hi Craig! How do you desirialize the anonymous types afterwards? I has also problems with circular references, then thought on our anonymous types approach but i'm not sure how about deserialize them... could you please provide an example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @byte_slave: Actually, I don't. My specific case is that I have to serialize to JSON, but don't need to deserialize.

Comment: Lucky you :) For me I could just mark my POCO class as serializable but the problem is that each time the EM changes it recreates the POCO classes and deletes the serialize attribute i previously wrote manually... this sucks... and its not practical to redo this over and over again... According to my quick research on how to serialize entities, the WCF serialization approach comes up, but I've no experience with WCF so i wanted to escape from it... anyway thanks for your input. Regards!

Answer (score 2):

We couldn't afford disabling ProxyCreation (the obvious solution). Instead we used [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to solve it. It's as simple as:

```
var dynamicProxyMember = _repository.FindOne<Member>(m=>m.Id = 1);
var member = new Member().InjectFrom(dynamicProxyMember) as Member;
```

Enjoy!